# Ruby Syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Entry, and it belongs to a Journal. Journals have the ability to be public, so an entry belonging to a public journal would also be public, it would get that attribute from the journal.

I have an unless statement that just transfers it to the index `unless @entry.is_public? || current_user.owns_entry? @entry`

I have one method that is simply

```
def is_public?
  journal.public_access?
end
```

the other is pretty straightforward. The issue i am having is that when i try to use `or` instead of `||` it works fine, but when i use `||` it gives me a `unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_end` I am trying to figure out what the issue is, as rubocop tells me that i need to be using `||` and i want to conform to ruby conventions. Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need parentheses around your argument, i.e. `current_user.owns_entry?(@entry)`.

```
unless @entry.is_public? || current_user.owns_entry?(@entry)
  # ...
end
```

Generally speaking you should use parentheses except in the simplest cases, both for readability and to avoid syntax issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for this, just getting use to ruby syntax so don't know all the nuances of it